# Collection property '__implicit_items' is null when setting transitions in Win Store app

Tags: windows-store-apps

When trying to set a transition using the Transitions collection on a Panel, like a Grid or something, like so:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Transitions>
     <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="300" />
  </Grid.Transitions>
</Grid>
```

I get the following error at runtime:

```
Collection property '__implicit_items' is null.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the collection.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
      <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="300" />
    </TransitionCollection>
  </Grid.Transitions>
</Grid>
```

Remember that XAML is just object-instantiation and property-setting mark-up and the Transitions property on the Grid is a collection and thus needs setting to a collection instance. No idea why it doesn't barf on the invalid type or why Intellisense suggests the bad syntax, but hey ho.